# Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch or future method

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i am calling a batch class from finish method of another batch class and facing the above error

**The method code:**

```
public class BatchPublicCampaignsToGoogle 
implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful, 
           Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){   
        if(newBatch == true) {           
            CalendarSettings__c c = 
                [Select Id, Name, CalendarId__c,
                 CalendarQuery__c,FieldToDisplay__c 
                 from CalendarSettings__c 
                 WHERE Name = 'Internal marketing Calendar' LIMIT 1] ;

            BatchPublicCampaign bjob = new BatchPublicCampaign();
            Database.executeBatch(bjob);
        }
    }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch or future method.
```

After finishing batch request, I am trying to call it (I have to call it for two times) again. So I call it.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex batch class Minimum version should be 27.0 i was using 25.0 thats why i was facing this issue!!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in your other question [Execution Confusion in Batch class Apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595406/execution-confusion-in-batch-class-apex), the ability to chain batch jobs together from the finish method was introduced in Winter 13.

Winter 13 corresponds to API version 26.0, so your batch class will need to use that or higher to use chaining.